# nginx short urls for mediawiki

Tags: nginx, mediawiki, url

I am trying to do short URLs for a MediaWiki site. The wiki is in a subdirectory `mydir` (http://www.example.com/mywiki). I've already set up rewrites in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` so that example.com redirects to example.com/mywiki.

Currently the URL is like `http://www.example.com/mywiki/index.php?title=Main_Page`. I want to clean up the url so that it looks like `http://www.example.com/mywiki/Main_Page`. I am having quite a bit of trouble doing this. I am not familiar with regular expressions or the syntax that the nginx config files use.

This is what I currently have:

```
server_name example.com www.example.com;

location / 
{
  rewrite ^.+ /mywiki/ permanent;
}

location /wiki/ 
{
  rewrite ^/mywiki/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /mywiki/index.php?title=$1&$2 last;
}
```

The second rewrite is obviously the one that's broken. It is based off of [*Page title -- nginx rewrite--root access* in the MediaWiki documentation](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/wiki/Page_title_--_nginx_rewrite--root_access).

When I try to load the site, the browser tells me I get infinite redirects. Does anyone who how I should go about fixing this issue? Or rather, what is the correct way to implement this, and what do all those symbols mean?

Comment: Do you have a location for `/mywiki/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very interesting expression they have there.  Their main manual page for short URLs has this to say:

> *These guides are old and are almost entirely bad advice.*

Anyway, let's see if we can simplify it a bit.

```
rewrite ^/wiki/([^\?]*) /mywiki/index.php?title=$1&$args last;
```

Note that you can't overlay the 'pretty' path (which you've put in the `location` block, so let's run with it) and the physical path; the norm is to use `/wiki/` as the pretty path (your `$wgArticlePath` config) and `/w/` as the physical path (your `$wgScriptPath` config).

So, all in all, something like this:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/$ /wiki/ permanent;
}

location /wiki/ {
  rewrite ^/wiki/([^\?]*) /mywiki/index.php?title=$1&$args last;
}
```

...and you'll need the PHP handling in some form as they've shown in their example, as well as to update your `Settings.php` with appropriate `$wgScriptPath` and `$wgArticlePath` settings, as well as setting `$wgUsePathInfo` to true.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed the issue. It seems that I had some confusion over the LocalSettings.php stuff, and my paths were messed up. Thank you!

Comment: @William Nice - I'm actually a little surprised I got that right on my first try, last time I set this up I kept missing things!  Maybe we should update their wiki page with the easier config ;)